# How to stop/pause/override Dojo confirmDialog hiding execution?

Tags: javascript, dojo, dijit.form

I have Dojo `confirmaDialog` and I need to implement a simple validation before submitting the form and to prevent modal from closing in case if there are validation errors.

This is what I have right now:

```
var followUpDialog = new ConfirmDialog({
    title: "Create new follow-up",
    content: handleMessageContent(),
    style: "width: 730px",
    onShow: function() {
        modalContainer = this.containerNode;
        fillInputFields(modalContainer);
    },
    onExecute: function () {
        if(!this.get("state")) {
            handleSubmit();
        } else {
            // Need something like event.preventDefault here.
        }

    },
    onCancel: function () {
        //Do nothing...
    }
});
```

Basically I need to somehow do nothing on certain condition when submit button is pressed.

Answer (score 1):

When you click on Ok `Button`, `onExecute` is called , and this last calls `hide` dialog function.

you can add custom code to Okbutton Click event  , or Just overide the `ConfirmDialog.js` and create your custom event ; by example

First overide the ConfirmDialog :

```
CustomConfirmDialog = declare([ConfirmDialog],{
    postCreate:function(){
        this.inherited(arguments);
        //check if realy passed parm is a function
        if(typeof(this.submitFunction) == "function") {
            this.okButton.on("click",lang.hitch(this,function(evt){
                if(!this.submitFunction()) evt.preventDefault();

            }));
        }
    }
});
```

create your submit function :

```
submit = function(){
    //submit code
}
```

Then when instatiate this last send the sumbmit function in option params 
(Here it's sent as `submitFunction` name attribute) :

```
var followUpDialog = new CustomConfirmDialog({
      id:'myDialog',
      ...
      // function of submit
      submitFunction:submit,....
      .... 
}
```

Below fin  a workin example :

```js
require(["dijit/ConfirmDialog", "dojo/_base/declare","dojo/on", "dijit/form/Button","dijit/registry","dojo/_base/lang","dojo/ready"],
 function(ConfirmDialog,declare,On,Button,registry,lang,ready){
  i=0;
        
  // sample function to submit your form
  submit = function(){
            //Swap between true and false.
         i ? ++i : --i;
            return i;
        }
        
        // overide ConfirmDialog
        CustomConfirmDialog = declare([ConfirmDialog],{
          postCreate:function(){
            this.inherited(arguments);
            //check if realy passed parm is a function
            if(typeof(this.submitFunction) == "function") {
              this.okButton.on("click",lang.hitch(this,function(evt){
                if(!this.submitFunction()) evt.preventDefault();
                
              }));
            }
          }
        });


        ready(function(){
          
            registry.byId("btn").on("click",function(e){
              followUpDialog.show();
         });
      // instantiate new custom dialog
         var followUpDialog = new CustomConfirmDialog({
      id:'myDialog',
      title: "Create new follow-up",
      content: "content !",
      style: "width: 730px",
                  //send submit function here
      submitFunction:submit,
      onShow: function() {
       //modalContainer = this.containerNode;
       //fillInputFields(modalContainer);
      },
      onExecute: function (e) {
       console.log("execute called");
      },
      onCancel: function () {
       //Do nothing...
      }
   });
         
        })
    }
);
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  dojoConfig = {isDebug: true, async: true, parseOnLoad: true}
</script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.8.3/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body class="claro">
  <div data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" id="btn"> click me </div>
</body>
```

Here also a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bRIMOs/h1coaceL/)